# About the mouse tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Notwithstanding the fact that people often confuse mouse (the physical object) and cursor (the thing on the screen), the [mouse](/questions/tagged/mouse) tag has a description related to Perl:

> Mouse is an object system for Perl that provides a subset of Moose's functionality. It aims to be highly compatible with Moose, has faster start up times and no dependencies.

but is used in 99.8% of cases as meaning the physical object (or its onscreen representation).

There are 2 items for the "real" meaning (Perl) of Mouse that I can find [mouse+perl](/questions/tagged/mouse%2bperl). The other 862 items in [mouse](/questions/tagged/mouse) are, by that definition, mistagged.

So, do we want to resolve this, and if so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Feel free to [edit the tag wiki excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/423) with what you feel is right, then assuming you have less than 20K reputation, it will require two 10K members to approve this and you're all done. :)

The current tag wiki excerpt was created by [Perl developer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/58089/eric-johnson) so this explains why it looks like this.

Comment: I kinda feel bad about officializing the co-opting of this tag, but I guess I can rely on the wisdom of 10Kers. The 2 Perl related cases, though, I wonder if a "mouse-perl" be appropriate.

Comment: Don't feel bad, that's what all this "peer review" is all about. Regarding `mouse-perl` I dunno, maybe just `perl`?

Comment: `perl-mouse` looks better.

Comment: @BrAvada It does. Great idea, tag created.